# Changing what is being pointed to in a C function

Tags: c

How can I get this function to change what x is pointing to in the following:

```
void test(const int *x)
```

Comment: You don't change the contents of `x`. You could cast away constness, but why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void test(const int *x)
{
    *((int *) x) = 42;
}
```

But if your object pointed at is `const`, you will invoke undefined behavior, like in:

```
const int bla = 58;
test(&bla);   // undefined behavior when the function is executed
```

This is ok:

```
int blop = 67;
test(&blop);
```

You rather want to change the prototype of your `test` function if you intend to modify the object pointed at.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pointer to a `const int`. You can't use it to change the value that it points to.

Comment: Here's the thing: "change what x is pointing to" is ambiguous. Does he mean "...so that x points somewhere else" or "...so that the thing x points to has a new value"?

Answer (score 1):

```
void test(const int *x)
```

The const here specifies that the function is not allowed to modify the pointee. If you want to modify the pointee declare your function like this:

```
void test(int *x)
```

Of course, if you meant that you wanted `x` to point at a different object, then you can simply assign to `x` in the body of the function. But that does not sound very likely to be what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a C compiler, but this C++ should work the same:

```
void test(const int **x)
{
    static const int newx = 123;
    *x = &newx;
}

int main()
{
    const int Temp = 999;

    const int* y = &Temp; 

    test(&y);
}
```